# Lollipop style loading spinner by css

Tags: css, css-animations, animate.css

I want to create a loading spinner in my webpage which is as same as an android Lollipop loading spinner...Is there any method for creating this by css?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://codepen.io/teamturret/pen/OPQzxN) url

```
.circle-loader {
    margin-left: 48%;  
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #009688;
    stroke-width: 5;
    animation: dash 2s ease infinite,rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1,95;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dasharray: 85,95;
        stroke-dashoffset: -25;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 85,95;
        stroke-dashoffset: -93;
    }
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```